# Grunt keeps removing my absolute paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have references to some external JS files in my index.html like this:

```
<!-- build:js(app) /scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Every time I run `grunt serve` ([generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)), the initial slashes are removed (`"/bower_components/..."` → `"bower_components/..."`), which ruins my pages >1 steps down in the hierarchy.

Is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/issues/43#issuecomment-33799772:

```
'bower-install': {
  myTask: {
    fileTypes: {
      html: {
        replace: {
          js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will likely have to un- and re-install grunt-bower-install to use this new type of configuration. You should also consider using [`<base href="/">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) as well.

Comment: `<base href="/">` alone definitely works. There must be an issue with how you're serving your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this. I always ignored the <base href="/">

Answer (score 3):

I am using the `angular-generator` with `yo` and this is what worked for me:

`Gruntfile.js` (line 160ish)

```
bowerInstall: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
    fileTypes: {
      html: {
        replace: {
          js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>',
          css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{filePath}}" />'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why my `bower-install` config looks different, but this is how I got it to work:

Original settings:

```
'bower-install': {
    app: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
        replace: {
            js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>'
        }
    }
},
```

Change:

```
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
```

(removing the ending slash)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I put the base tag below the stylesheet section. Once I placed it on top it worked like a charm:

> ```
>   <base href="/"> <!- correct!! -->
>   <!-- build:css(client) app/vendor.css -->
>   <!-- bower:css -->
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
>   <!-- endbower -->
>   <base href="/"> <!- wrong!!! -->
> ```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but made my day. Thank you!